# Is Windows vulnerable because its sudo equivalent does not require a password?

Tags: windows, linux, sudo, uac, authentication

On Windows from Vista and onwards, you have to press through an UAC dialog to perform something that requires admin rights like installing or uninstalling programs. On Linux to become root, you have to type your whole password.

Why is that? Why is there no passwordless sudo in any Linux distribution? Does the lack of password protection on Windows means that it is vulnerable in some way? If so, I'd like to see a proof of concept or a explanation of exactly how.

**Update:** Thanks for the answers, but they don't address my main question. To be more precise: If there *isn't* a vulernability in the Windows way, then why does Linux distros keep pestering the user to have to enter a password all the time? If there *is* a vulernability, then exactly how can it be exploited?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your user level on either system, actually.

**Linux**

Linux allows very extensive user rights management, most of which can be controlled through `visudo` (i.e. "The sudoers file").  You can control who has admin access (root privileges) and to what type of executables.  They can either require a password to execute them -or- be allowed `nopass`, which is basically the equivalent to a Windows Administrator account.

**Windows**

By default, the first account created is an admin account (Since new windows, by default does not have a `root` (or "Administrator" in windows-lang) account).  What that means is then your usual user account acts as a linux admin with `nopass` set and behaves pretty similarly.

**Summary...**

Long-story-short, it is really down to how you set up your system.  Ubuntu, and most derivatives, act as windows in this way except they have `nopass` off - but your initial account is indeed an `admin` account.

Technically speaking, it is much better to use a traditional user account and only use elevated accounts for administrative work that shouldn't be terribly common after system set-up.

But, as @Eddy_Em said, all-be-it harshly, is that Windows sets up its users to not know/care about that type of restriction by default since XP.  You could set-it up yourself and have a typical user account and an admin account, then you would have to supply the user/pass to make changes (just use the user level account to login).

Answer (score 1):

No, neither Sudo nor UAC actually NEED a password. the point of both systems is to make sure the operator is absolutely sure they want to do something as admin, not to check to see if they ARE admin. you can;t use sudo or uac unless you are authenticated under a admin-capable account. this is why the sudo password on most systems is the users password itself.  Note that in Vista, windows RUNAS support was weak, so some shops used UAC as a Runas alternative, but that is not its purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The UAC can actually be disabled through Control Panel. The security of the application depends on the privileges of the logged on account and the exposed surface area of the system.